# Insert element between index x, y

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to insert list item between  list elements:

```
$('#deals-providers dt').each(function(index) {
        if (index == 10) {          

            $(this).insertBefore($('<dt/>').text('More item'));

        }
});
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: How/Where is `index` updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
$('#deals-providers dt:eq(9)').after('<dt>More item</dt>');
```

The [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selects the item at that index.

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/ezopix/edit#javascript,html,live)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

edit:

```
$('dt:nth(10)').before('<dt>More item</dt>');
```

Comment: I don't think you want the [10] there as that gives you the dom element rather than the 11th jQuery object in the collection - http://jsbin.com/ezopix/2/edit#preview

Comment: I try   $('#deals-providers dt')[10].insertBefore($('<dt>More</dt>'));
too, but all above gives me jQuery error, probably it is old version

Comment: @jadept No, it's because it's trying to call insertBefore on the 11th dom element which doesn't have a method called insertBefore.

Comment: this works on jsbin for the example of Richard
$('dt:nth(10)').before('<dt>More item</dt>');

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [:nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

See: http://jsfiddle.net/L2tk2/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#deals-providers dt').each(function(index) {
        if (index == 10) {          
            $(this).insertBefore($('dt:contains("More item")'));
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jQuery#eq` method to return an element at a designated index. This will return a jQuery object, unlike `jQuery#get`, which returns an element node.

```
$('#deals-providers dt').eq(10).before(
  $('<dt>').text('More text')
);
```